# Odoo View inheritance: how to modify the domain for the Payment Journal field in the Account Payment form

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have a custom Odoo module which, among other things, records payments. In order to do this I am using the Make Payment form from the Accounting module.

I want to allow the user to filter the options in the Payment Journal drop down based on a flag on the `account.journal` entity, so I have extended the entity as follows:

```py
class AccountJournal(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'account.journal'
  available_as_payment_method = fields.Boolean(string='Available as payment method')
```

... and added the field in the view used to edit the payment journal:

```xml
<field name="available_as_booking_payment_method"/>
```

This functionality works as expected and the field exists in the database.

Finally I extended the payment form:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="payment_form_update_form">
  <field name="name">payment_form_update</field>
  <field name="model">account.payment</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_payment_form" />
  <field name="type">form</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='journal_id']" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="domain">[('available_as_booking_payment_method', '=', True)]</attribute>
     <!-- <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute> -->
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

For some reason, if I modify the domain attribute, it is not applied. The screenshot shows the existing domain in the Odoo debug popup - this remains unchanged with my view or the default view.

If I apply the `invisible` flag, the field disappears, so I know that the view and the xpath are correct.

Grateful for any help as to why the domain is not being applied.

Thanks in advance

[image: The default Odoo payment form (account.view_account_payment_form)]
[image: The debug popup for the Pament Journal field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **journal_id** has a domain definition in the .py file, you can try override the domain in the .py file too, something like this:

```
journal_id = fields.Many2one(domain=[('available_as_booking_payment_method', '=', True),('type', 'in', ('bank', 'cash'))])
```

I hope this answer can be helful for you.